# Visual Studio 2022 with MAUI instructs to load XCode version 0.0

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-2022, maui

When I am in a Xamarin Forms project, there is no problem connecting to the Mac.
When I open a MAUI project, it doesn't connect.
I was behind by one update, but yesterday I got a message saying Visual Studio wouldn't work with XCode 14.1 and to install XCode 0.0.
I updated Visual Studio, and now it still fails to connect. But, now the error blows by and I don't see what it is. I think it's the same thing.
Visual Studio 2022 17.4.4
XCode 14.1
MAC OS Ventura 13.0.1

Here's the output display:

```
Initializing IDB environment...
Server Settings:
- mlaunch path: 
- Xcode version: 14.1
- Xcode path: /Applications/Xcode.app

Starting disconnection from 10.8.11.30...
Validating Mac operating system version compatibility...
Starting disconnection from 10.8.11.30...
The connection to '10.8.11.30' has been finished
```

I tried updating Visual Studio and thought that might fix things, but it basically got worse, because I can't confirm the error message that is causing the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft released Visual Studio 2022 Professional 17.5 Preview 6 which fixed this issue. Now it connects to the Mac, but it drops the connection several times a day. So, that's a baby step in the right direction.

[Here is the issue on Microsoft's website.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-Professional-2022-on-Windo/10270498?port=1025&fsid=035945e5-f341-4824-b89a-82e1b8768e7e&ref=native&refTime=1678124249376&refUserId=757fe091-a6a4-693d-90cd-46edf19dbaa1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That could be something with Visual Studio for Mac. You could **update the Visual Studio for Mac** first. The final builds of Xcode 14.1 are ready for you to test both on Xamarin and MAUI now.

You could also refer to [Xcode 14.1 Support · Issue #16659 · xamarin/xamarin-macios (github.com)](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16659) and  install the pkg files of Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac to your Mac if you don't want to update your Visual Studio for Mac.

[Xamarin.iOS 16.1.1.27](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/82c00e2b-6bfe-4450-8691-5cb8464c37dc/e67bae84054f6aa4e221ab7f63edf78a/xamarin.ios-16.1.1.27.pkg)

[Xamarin.Mac 9.0.0.27.pkg](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/82c00e2b-6bfe-4450-8691-5cb8464c37dc/34dcb22cccb6f364e64346f6812b0adc/xamarin.mac-9.0.0.27.pkg)

Comment: I don't use VS on a Mac. I'm on Windows, and I just updated VS.

Comment: Did you use pair to mac?

Comment: Of course. How else does it pair to the Mac and report error messages?

Comment: Before I updated VS yesterday, sometimes it would say the XCode license can't be verified or something, because XCode is not installed on the Mac.

Comment: I just tried again, and I got:
The Xcode version installed on the Mac (14.1) is not compatible with this version of Visual Studio. This may cause unexpected warnings or errors when building and deploying iOS projects. Please install Xcode '0.0'. To download a specific version of Xcode, visit: https://developer.apple.com/downloads.

Comment: May i ask the version of Visual Studio for Mac on MacBook? Have you tried updating Visual Studio For Mac?

Comment: You could also try installing the pkg files in my answer to your mac.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, Visual Studio 2022 17.4.4 on Windows, and as I mentioned  in my previous comment. I don't use VS on the Mac. Why can't Visual Studio for Windows work as expected?

Comment: You could report a problem to Visual Studio. In Visual Studio, click **_Help_** -> **_Send_** **_a_** **_Feedback_** -> **_Report_** **_a_** **_Problem_** .

Comment: I have tried that. Your website displays a socket time out error when I try to login.

Comment: It's weird. I've tested just now and it worked well when sign in with my email.